# Calculation of resistor values which control LEDs through transistors and have pull-up / pull-down resistors attached

Tags: transistors, resistors, diodes, schematics, esp8266

During startup of ESP8266:

- GPIO15 needs to be LOW
- GPIO2 needs to be HIGH

I want to be able to turn on/off RGB LEDs connected to GPIO2, GPIO15 and GPIO4 via [MMBT2222ALT1G](http://www.tme.eu/en/Document/fd53f7282772c4b53c43aa6dcf874bac/mmbt2222.pdf) NPN transistors.

Data:

- Red: Uf = 2 V
- Green: Uf = 2.5 V
- Blue: Uf = 3.3 V
- If = 22 mA
- VCC = 3.3 V
- hFE = 10 (?)
- Vbe = 0.82 V (?)
- Vce = 0.3V (?)

Schematic:

[image]

I'm lost in my calculations of **R2, R21 and R22**. Some time ago I calculated them as follows on the schematic and the device was working properly but I guess I was just lucky.

So how should I calculate them properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to choose those resistor values so that the transistors operate in the saturation region ( as a switch).

From what I see in the schematic you provided each transistor is driving 4 LEDs, and you want the current through each LED to be 22 mA. Then the collector current through each transistor when driving its set of LEDs is 4x22mA=88mA.

With that information, you can figure out how to overdrive the base current so that the transistor are in saturation. That is, choose a \$\beta_{forced}\$ < \$\beta(min)\$ of your transistor. That will ensure the devices are in saturation.

Say, you pick \$\beta_{forced}\$  = \$\dfrac{\beta(min)}{5}\$ or for simplicity select it to be \$\beta_{forced}=10\$ as you have in your specs.

Then \$I_B=\dfrac{I_c}{\beta_{forced}}=\dfrac{88\text{mA}}{10}=8.8\text{mA}\$

You can now find the values for the base resistor using kirchoff's law

$$ R_B=\dfrac{V_{output}-V_{BE}}{I_B}$$

where \$V_{output}\$ is the voltage at the GPIO when high

You device worked because your values for \$R_B\$ provided enough overdrive current through the base to put the transistor in the saturation region.

For R2 you had 510 ohms, so

$$ I_B=\dfrac{5\text{v}-0.82\text{v}}{510\Omega}=8.20\text{mA}$$ assuming the gpio is 5V when high (\$\beta_{forced} \approx 10\$). Even if it were 3.3V, \$I_B=4.9\text{mA}\$ and (\$\beta_{forced} \approx 18\$), those currents are high enough to drive the transistor into saturation.

Also, if you check the datasheet, for a saturation voltage \$V_{ce}=0.3\text{V}\$, they were trying a base current of 15mA for a collector current of 150mA (\$\beta_{forced}=10\$).

**EDIT:** 
One of the comments added the fact the typical I/O pins have an output impedance of about 100 Ohms. This changes the base current a bit, but still keeps the device operating as a switch (\$\beta_{forced}\$ is still a fraction of \$\beta(\text{min}\$)).

From what I see in the datasheet for the ESP8266, you can configure your GPIOs as open drain, push-pull, etc. I don't know which of those settings you are using. But if you are using them as push-pull (can drive the output high or low) all the above is still valid after *startup*.

Now, I am guessing at start-up those GPIOs are high-impedance and you want a well defined status, that's why you're pulling down and pulling up the two GPIOs you mentioned. At start-up, your green LED, which is connected to the GPIO2 (pulled high) should light up not as bright as after start up (but you won't even notice), this is because the base current isn't as big to set a collector current of 88 mA. The base current should be about (leakage current into the gpio should be negligible):

$$ I_{B(@startup)} =\dfrac{V_{cc}-V_{BE}}{R_{pullup}+R_B}=0.236\text{mA}$$

If we say \$\beta\$=100, then the device is probably not a switch at this instant (is in the active region), \$I_C=\beta I_B\$=23.6mA (\$V_{ce}\approx 3\text{V}\$, and so it is indeed in the active region), which you have to divide by four (since you have four LEDs), so each LED will have \$I_F\approx\$5.9mA. That's why the LEDs won't be as bright as when you are getting 22mA through each one of them. But this only happens at startup, which is probably unnoticeable.

The issue that I can see is that at startup, GPIO2 may not be high enough due to the base current being sufficiently high to generate a considerable voltage drop across the pullup. That is,

$$v_{CC}-I_{B(@startup)}R_{pullup}=V_{gpio2}=0.94\text{V}$$

And the ESP8266 will read a logic high if it is at least 0.75*Vcc=2.48V as per the datasheet.

You don't have this issue with the pulldown.

I don't know what the central block of your schematic is, I've assumed those transistors connect directly to the GPIOs.

Ideally you may want to isolate your transistor connected to gpio2 from this output, say for a couple milliseconds, that way the base current won't put that gpio in an unknown state at startup (maybe add some kind of delay mechanism?). After startup, you could 're-connect' you transistor associated with gpio2, and all the above calculations for \$R_B\$ still apply (push-pull config).

After startup, the pulldown, looks like a load to GPIO15 when driven high, it doesn't affect your base resistor calculation, but you don't want to draw more current from that pin than the max rating (right now it is about .33mA being drawn from the pulldown (3.3V/10k)). The total current pulled from that gpio is going to be the base current plus the current through the pulldown resistor. But I don't see this as an issue as long as you are under the max rating.

I hope this is helpful and hope other people add to this some ways of addressing something like this.

Comment: The OP was explicit that \$V_{CC}=3.3\:\textrm{V}\$. No guessing required. And typical I/O pins will include somewhere around \$100\:\Omega\$ output impedance, which compares significantly to the base resistor values in this case. But I don't think that changes your conclusions.

Comment: So, you're saying that the values of resistors that I calculated are alright? It would seem that the best value would be 281 ohms. I don't get it. Shouldn't we take into account those pull-up and pull-down resistors? And maybe some other factors as well?

Comment: @Defozo the values you choose work fine. 281 Ohms work fine too (Ib=8.8mA, for an Ic=88mA), it keeps the device working as a switch. You only care about the base current in order to have those transistors working as a switch. And the base current will depend on the output from those gpios (3.3V), Vbe, and Rb. Just keep your forced beta value (Ic/Ib) well under the minimum beta specified in the datasheet. So Ic/Ib<25, for example, would do.

Comment: @Defozo sorry, I may have missed something from the schematic. I get what you are saying now. Are you going to drive those LEDs (blue and green) after startup?

Comment: Yes. I need GPIO15 to be LOW and GPIO2 to be HIGH during startup because ESP8266 needs them in these states to run in proper mode. After startup, I want to drive those LEDs (red, green and blue).

Comment: @Sixto Cabrera Thank you for your great answer. You are right about GPIO2 not being set high on start-up. However, you didn't provide any answer addressing this issue. Is it unsolvable problem? Couldn't I just put there a resistor with higher resistance value to leverage those aspects? Just enough to set GPIO2 high on start-up and still be able to turn off the LEDs after start-up? It doesn't matter if they blink for a fraction of a second during start-up. What matters for me, is to be able to control them after start-up and keep GPIO2 high during start-up.

Comment: I could make some changes to the PCB in the next order, however, unfortunately, I already ordered some PCBs with this design.

Comment: @Defozo you may use a PNP transistor for green LEDs instead of the NPN that you have. Your LEDs need to have the anode pins connected to the collector and the cathode pins to ground through a resistor. (you'll be switching the power now, not the ground). One thing, though, if you choose to go this path, you need a logic low to turn on the green LEDs, and a logic high to turn them off (opposite to what you do with the other LEDs). You may want to use 3.3V to power the green LEDs (you could keep the other LEDs the same). Google PNP as a switch. This is just my humble opinion on approaching this.

Comment: But those are RGB LEDs so I can't do that and still use them. Any idea how to solve the problem in the current state of PCB?

Comment: @Defozo Maybe a logic level mosfet would work since once its input capacitance is charged up, no current  flows into the gate so the voltage at the gpio pin will be high enough. Now, the gate has to be charged up fast enough so that the chip reads that pin high when it does so. I don't know how fast this needs to be, but the gate capacitance of a mosfet can be charged up on the order of microseconds. Since the mosfet is actually voltage controlled device you can relax the gate resistor or even better the pullup, say to 4.7k, instead of 10k. That will speed things up a bit and may do the job.

Comment: @Defozo Those changes are with regards to the green LEDs driver. You can keep the other the same. Also, you need to make sure, you drive the gpio low, when you need those leds off. Maybe a something like this for the mosfet: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/FDN337N-1007955.pdf